# ¿Alguna forma de pixelar texto en html?

Tags: html, css

tengo la presentación de un proyecto en la escuela que ya esta en producción pero los datos que se muestran en el proyecto son confidenciales. entonces, para llenar datos que simulen la realidad costaría mucho tiempo, por eso mi duda, si hay alguna manera de pixelar los textos que se muestran en html.

Comment: Confidenciales? explica bien eso, si no deben mostrarse simplemente quitalos de tu html!

Comment: Se muestran direcciones y nombre de clientes reales en gráficas y reportes

Comment: Lo que tengo entendido es que quieres que se vea borroso,si son datos confidenciales deberías de no mostrarlos y ya, pero si es necesario hacerlo como dices podrías intentar agregar alguna fuente de esta pagina https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/style/Pixel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias utilizar la propiedad `filter:blur(n)` de css para dicho caso:

Ejemplo:

```css
.desenfoque{
   filter: blur(5px);
}
.desenfoquehover:hover{
  filter: blur(1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="desenfoque">
Texto que no se lee
</div>

<div class="desenfoquehover">
pasa el raton por aqui
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, es lo que necesito